# javabean: How to call a method declared in a javabean (A) from another javabean (B)

Tags: jsp

how can i call from a javabean (for instance class A) a method declared in another javabean (for instance class b)?

I make this:

```
    package pack;
    public class prova{

        public String stringa(){
            String  s = "ciao";
            return s;               
        }               

    }
```

How can i call the method stringa() from an

Comment: I do not understand the query. Make an instance of B in A and then call b.method() or else make the method static in B and call B.method.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm an idiot. 
I had to make an instance of that class as u said :)
Thank you man